# What exactly does CGRectMake (or other Make functions) do?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I am wish to implement a similar pattern to what Apple do with `CGRectMake()` and all their other  `~Type~Make()` functions. What is the code for CGRectMake... I understand what it does, but more specifically I would like to know what it does (in terms of stack, heap et al.)?

Is it just:

```
inline function CGRectMake(CGFloat x,  CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height) {
    CGRect rect;
    rect.x = x;
    rect.y = y;
    rect.width = width;
    rect.height = height;
    return rect;
}
```

Or is there more to it (and to be learnt!)?

**edit**
Is there a reason they don't make it a constructor?

Comment: Constructors are for C++; this is glorified C.  The compiler will build the `CGRect` struct on the stack and generate code to copy it back to the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you command-click on `CGRectMake` Xcode shows you its implementation. You almost had it ;-)

```
CG_INLINE CGRect
CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height)
{
  CGRect rect;
  rect.origin.x = x; rect.origin.y = y;
  rect.size.width = width; rect.size.height = height;
  return rect;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you see is it, since it's a `struct` not a class there really ins't much more to it. Since it's a `struct` it is stored in the stack.

The `CGRectMake` function is just a convenience method for make a `CGRect`.

---

Also see the great answer by [Matthias Bauch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/457406/matthias-bauch) about <kbd>cmd</kbd> + mouse click on a method to get to it's implementation.

You can als <kbd>alt</kbd>+ mouse click to get the methods description.